# Can anyone identify this vine?

Tags: identification, vines

With little kids in the Indianapolis yard, I want to make sure this vine is safe. You can see what the leaf looks like and what the vine looks like in the photos below:

*Click either photo for full size*
[image]
[image]

Comment: The links worked, but Stack Exchange prefers to have images hosted at imgur.com so that the photos will still be accessible if you clean up your dropbox (or flickr or ...).  Once you have 10 rep, you can upload photos directly using the picture control above the editor (6th from the left, looks like a picture frame)/

Comment: If the upload from my iPad to imgur.com had worked, I might have used it; my first upload still shows continual network activity but no uploaded file, and that's on a 25mb/sec up & down network. I have no idea of what's wrong. DropBox worked perfectly and very easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a grapevine. Perfectly safe.

Comment: Yup, but a wild or a cultivated grape?

Comment: Don't know, but interested only for curiosity. @Michelle's answer was perfect.

Comment: That is beyond my skill level, kevinsky. :) Either way, you can make stuffed vine leaves, and that would make me happy. Glad that was what you needed, twizzard.